# Swiftui how to build an async counter for swiftui

Tags: swiftui, async-await

For a personal app that fetches a set of data from the net I have have been trying to build a view that that tracks how many have returned.  First attempt led to classic intermittent data races during counter updates.  Digging some more I've look at "actors" to implement an atomic counter.

I have a solution, as shown below, but with the async/awaits it feels ugly, as it has Published counters wrapped around local class counters wrapped around the actor counters.  The sample allows the user to click as many times as wanted, with a random delay (to simulate net connections) and then watch the counter catch up.

Can anyone suggest some simplifications (and/or unseen issues) with the code ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var pickerCounter = ObservableCounter()
  @State private var buttonClickCount = 0
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Clicks recorded so far: \(pickerCounter.counterValue)")
      Button("Start async action") {
         buttonClickCount += 1
         Task { pickerCounter.increment() }
      }
      Text("Button clicks \(buttonClickCount)")
    }
  }
}

actor CounterActor {
    private(set) var count: Int = 0
    
    /// Increment in internal counter by the given value
    func increment(by increment: Int = 1) -> Int {
        count += increment
        return count
    }
}

class ObservableCounter: ObservableObject {
  @Published var counterValue: Int = 0
  private var count: Int = 0
  private var counter = CounterActor()
  
  func increment( by value: Int = 1) {
    Task {
      let delay = Int.random(in: 0...100)
      usleep(useconds_t(60_000*delay))
      await setCount(counter.increment())
    }
  }
  
  @MainActor func setCount(_ count:Int) {
    counterValue = count
  }
}
```

TIA Alan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably making it harder than it needs to be. You can isolate the counter to the main actor, and it's best to surface asynchronous operations as such rather than hiding the async nature behind a facade (e.g. let the caller define the asynchronous context, rather than starting a task internally):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var pickerCounter = ObservableCounter()
  @State private var buttonClickCount = 0
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Clicks recorded so far: \(pickerCounter.counterValue)")
      Button("Start async action") {
         buttonClickCount += 1
         Task { try await pickerCounter.increment() }
      }
      Text("Button clicks \(buttonClickCount)")
    }
  }
}
```

And your counter:

```swift
@MainActor
class ObservableCounter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counterValue: Int = 0
    
    func increment( by value: Int = 1) async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(.random(in: 0...10)))
        counterValue += value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I had failed to grasp that annotating @MainActor to the class effectively makes it a singleton which negates the need for my CounterActor as a discrete singleton.  I had got that it causes the classes to run on the main thread and had viewed running on the main thread to be best, sort of, used for UI stuff only.  In this sample case there is no penalty for running on the main thread.

Comment: @MainActor doesn't make it a singleton, it makes it guaranteed to execute on the main actor. In the normal case, you do pretty much everything on the main actor / thread _unless_ it's blocking or high-impact

Comment: Yes, 30 seconds thought and I should have realised that 8-(.  Somewhere along the track, I had lost the connection to normal case being of the use of the main thread and had acquired the false perception of it being, sort of, reserved for UI activities.  A mental reset has been handy.  Alan.